# CSS clip corners?

Tags: css

Is there a simple way to style element like this?

[image: Example]

Supposed to be used on a mobile so CSS3 is fully available. Can't think of a simple way. Images are out of question.

It has to be this blocky and there supposed to be a text within (this is a blocky 8-bit button)

Comment: Are you looking for rounded corners or little squares removed from them?

Comment: A picture is usually worth a thousand words, but in this case, you need a few more words to explain the picture.  Or do you actually want *exactly* what is shown?

Comment: Yea that's the whole point. Squares subtracted from the bg on the corners. It's a part of an 8-bit browser game. Hope it makes sense why I need that blocky looks :) And there supposed to be a text in this element

Comment: diff widths, fixd height http://imm.io/kZvh http://imm.io/kZvn

Comment: Just updated my answer; it meets all your requirements as far as I can see!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This jumps off of feeela's beginnings, but it's different enough to warrant its own answer.

1. Rather than putting a colored block overly, it only adds red-colored elements, allowing background to show through. HOWEVER, to calculate it properly (so that they're square corners!) I had to set a fixed <strike>width</strike> height. There's probably some sort of wacky way to do this with percentages, but for proof of concept it was too headachey to contemplate. Since the requirement is for fixed height variable width, this should work.
2. The pseudo-elements need to have content or they will "collapse". The content can be empty, but that property needs to be set.

CSS:

```css
/* main button block */
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}

/* common background color to all */
.button, .button::before, .button::after {
    background-color: #f00;
}

/* shared styles to make left and right lines */
.button::before, .button::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 5px;
    top: 5px;

}

/* pull the left 'line' out to the left */
.button::before {
    left: -5px;
}

/* pull the right 'line' out to the right */
.button::after {    
    right: -5px;
}
```

​

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3R9c5/2/

Comment: Perfect! Just perfect! Thanks broheim!

Comment: No worries! It was an enjoyable challenge. :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tmWdx/5/)?

HTML:

```
<div class="block">(text goes here)</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {background:#1990D7;}
.block {background:#FF1200; line-height:52px; margin:8px auto; width:359px;
   position:relative; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; color:yellow}
.block::before {display:inline-block; background:#FF1200; content:'';
   position:absolute; top:4px; left:-4px; bottom:4px; width:4px;}
.block::after {display:inline-block; background:#FF1200; content:'';
   position:absolute; top:4px; right:-4px; bottom:4px; width:4px;}
```

Edit: updated after the latest insights into the demands of the question.

Comment: Yes, because with 4px corners, the outer edges will have to be 8px less than the main rectangle. Hm. What if we apply the extra rectangles to the left and right instead of the top and bottom? Will that work? Is the height fixed?

Comment: I don't see any HTML in there, but here is a new fiddle, where the sides don't depend on the width or the height of the main block: http://jsfiddle.net/tmWdx/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can insert each of that four blocky-corners by appending pseudo elements via `::before` or `::after`.

e.g.:

```
.button {
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
}

/* corner top left */
.button::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 5px; height: 5px;
    background: #00f;
}

/* corner top right */
.button::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    width: 5px; height: 5px;
    background: #00f;
}

/* corner bottom left */
/* … */
```

Comment: I like the beginnings of this approach. The tricky part is figuring out how to get that 4th corner. ;-) Might need to add ONE extra bit of markup to get'r done. D'oh, also it doesn't seem to work at all: http://jsfiddle.net/3R9c5/

Comment: Background can be different, I have a gradient background on this page :( Yea I know, 8 bit and gradient like whaaaaaaaa. Still.

Comment: @GregPettit You mean like using bottom:0; right:0; to place the last corner? I can't figure how it could be a problem. Why might you need more markup for it?

Comment: @hradac Because what exactly will be there? You have the main element (.button) which is a red rectangle. You have the ::after pseudo-element for one of the "subtracting" blocks, and the ::before for another. Come to think of it, we're down two blocks.  Where do the other two come from without more markup? In any event, if the blocks have to be literally subtracted (rather than the illusion of subtraction) so that a gradient background can show through, this approach won't work as-is. But what you COULD try to do is make a line above and a line below.

Comment: I don't like the idea of subtracting corners. What if the background around the element is not supposed to be a solid color (#00f in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS border-radius attribute

Comment: A Pixel is a square, but I assume you don't mean that – so your answer is: no. Border-radius will create rounded borders.

Comment: Wrong answer, didn't actually see the squares!

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) will help you. Or you can just add new class, "cadre" for example

```
.cadre
{
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

to your css file, then affect it to the div.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `border-radius` can accomplish that. This is the simplest way I can think of:

http://jsfiddle.net/DpLdt/

CSS:

```
body {
background:blue;
}
div#clipcorners {
width:500px;
height:200px;
background:red;
position:relative;
margin:100px auto;
}
span#a,span#b {
position:absolute;
width:10px;
height:180px;
top:10px;
background:red;
}
span#a {
left:-10px;
}
span#b {
right:-10px;
}
```

​

HTML:

```
<div id="clipcorners">
<span id="a">
</span>
<span id="b">
</span>
</div>​
```